# Custom DataModule breaks inheritance in Delphi

Tags: delphi, inheritance, custom-component

I have a Custom DatModule (say TMyDataModule) to which I wished to add a published property (an enumerated type) so that the property would be accessible in the Object Inspector (at least for descendants).

I added the unit to an existing design-time package and added registration code like "RegisterCustomModule(TMyDataModule, TCustomModule);"; uninstalled, rebuilt, re-installed the package.

When I open an existing DataModule that was created by inheriting from TMyDataModule, the property shows up in the OI. So far so good.

BUT any existing (or newly created) DMs that were/are created by inheriting from TMydataModule, once they  are created, they no longer inherit from TMyDatModule. If I edit the DFM for any of these descendants and try to change the opening "object" back to "inherited", Delphi just changes it back when I exit the DFM.

And components  defined on TMyDataModule no longer appear on the "form" at design-time and one cannot reference them e.g. when setting properties etc. (They are accessible in code, but ....)

As requested, an example.

This is the parent class (=TMyDataModule"):

```
  TdmSQLBase = class(TDataModule)
    sspMeta: TSQLStoredProc;
    dspMeta: TDataSetProvider;
    cdMeta: TClientDataSet;
    dsMeta: TDataSource;
    conMeta: TSQLConnection;
    cdAllIndexes: TClientDataSet;
    sdsMeta: TSQLDataSet;
    procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SQLConnectionBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);

    procedure CDSAfterPost_Upd(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure CDSBeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure CDSBeforeRefresh(DataSet: TDataSet) ;

    ......................  etc etc etc ....................
  published
    property DBApplication : TDBApplication read FDBApplication write FDBApplication default daHeadOffice ;
  end;

var
  dmSQLBase: TdmSQLBase = nil;

This is a descendant originally inherited from the above:


type
  TdmDBCheck = class(TdmSQLBase)
    cddata: TClientDataSet;
    dspData: TDataSetProvider;
    sdsData: TSQLDataSet;
    conData: TSQLConnection;
    dsData: TDataSource;
    cdDatabase: TClientDataSet;
    dsDatabase: TDataSource;
    dspDataBase: TDataSetProvider;
    sdsDatabase: TSQLDataSet;
    dspIndex: TDataSetProvider;
    conINdex: TSQLConnection;
    sdsIndex: TSQLDataSet;
    cdIndex: TClientDataSet;
    dsIndex: TDataSource;
    cdAllTest: TClientDataSet;

    ............... etc etc etc .....
  end;

var
  dmDBCheck: TdmDBCheck;
```

---

Now, before registering the custom module, one could at design-time e.g. assign the SQLconnection property of sdsData to say conMeta defined on the parent (and it would apprear in the drop-down list of connections just as "conMeta"). (Let's not get into the desirablility of doing that.) With the Custom Module registered, conMeta does not appear in the OI for the descendant. However, dmSQLBase.conMeta does. BUT selecting this will likely give an AV at runtime, unless one instantiates the parent separately - which rather defeats the purpose and is yukky anyway.

The problem, which is not huge, is that for some existing descendants their DFMs will contain references like "conMeta" in the above example. With the module registered, delphi drops/ignores 
those references as they are "invalid" (so they become nil pointers at runtime).

I am actually coming around to the view that the behaviour with the module registered is "cleaner". (Those components like conMeta also do not appear on the child's "form" which is a plus).
But if I retain the registration I need to find and correct any such references, and I just want to understand what the hell is going on.

Comment: This would benefit from an example.  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what is missing for you is to register a **library expert**. In your design time package you should register your library expert as follows:

```
RegisterLibraryExpert(TNewMyDataModuleExpert.Create); // <-- Your library expert
RegisterCustomModule(TMyDataModule, TCustomModule);
```

The procedure `RegisterLibraryExpert` is located in `ExptIntf` unit, so you have to add it to you uses clause.

A library expert is an IDE add-on that creates a new item in the Delphi New Items window. It will allow you to correctly generate an unit (`.pas` and `.dfm` files) for your new IDE module (your new `TDataModule` descendant).

`TNewMyDataModuleExpert` is a class declared as follows:

```
TNewMyDataModuleExpert = class(TIExpert)
  procedure Execute; override;
  function GetAuthor: string; override;
  function GetComment: string; override;
  function GetGlyph: HICON; override;
  function GetIDString: string; override;
  function GetName: string; override;
  function GetMenuText: string; override;
  function GetPage: string; override;
  function GetState: TExpertState; override;
  function GetStyle: TExpertStyle; override;
end;
```

`TIExpert` is declared in `ExptIntf`. Most overriden methods have the purpose to tightly integrate this expert to the IDE. The `Execute` method, however, is the most important one and may have an implementation like this:

```
procedure TNewMyDataModuleExpert.Execute;
var
  creator: TMyDataModuleCreator;
  modIntf: TIModuleInterface;
begin
  modIntf := nil;
  creator := TMyDataModuleCreator.Create;
  try
    modIntf := ToolServices.ModuleCreate(creator, [cmAddToProject, cmShowSource,
                                                   cmShowForm, cmUnNamed]);
  finally
    modIntf.Free;
    creator.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Notice that there is another class here, `TMyDataModuleCreator`. This one is responsible for ultimately creating the new module and is declared like this:

```
TMyDataModuleCreator = class(TIModuleCreator)
  function Existing: Boolean; override;
  procedure FormCreated(Form: TIFormInterface); override;
  function GetAncestorName: string; override;
  function GetFileName: string; override;
  function GetFileSystem: string; override;
  function GetFormName: string; override;
  function NewModuleSource(const UnitName, Form, Ancestor: string): string; override;
end;
```

`TIModuleCreator` is declared in `Editintf`. The most important method here is `NewModuleSource` that should return the source code that you want to be generated for your new module. What you return here will be the exact source code for the newly generated unit. You can add, for instance, comments, a specific uses clause or anything you like.

Another important method is `GetAncestorName` what should return the string `'MyDataModule'`, without the usual `T` prefix.

In my case, the `Existing` method always returns `False`. Sorry, but at this moment I don´t remember why. Other `string` returning methods return an empty string.

The `FormCreated` method allows you to perform operations over the just created object, if you need to.

I guess this will work for you!

Comment: Alex, thanks for your detailed answer. I'm still digesting it. However, I suspect that this just streamlines the process of generating a new form - I think the result will be the same as adding the "base" unit to the project and then inheriting a new form/datamodule from it. But I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @TomB: alright Tom, take your time. However, what I can tell you about this is that the result is not the same as creating an ordinary DataModule and manually changing it to descend from your new class. In this case, it´s important that the DFM file begins with `object`, not `inherited`, because this is to inform the Delphi streaming system that the form/module uses visual inheritance. That´s why you change the DFM to `inherited` and the IDE changes id back to `object`.

Comment: @TomB: did you call `RegisterNoIcon` in your design package to register `TMyDataModule` class?

Comment: Alex: Thanks for that additional - just snowed under. I take your point about it being different from inheriting... I will check (but I'm sure you're right). NO I did not call RegisterNoIcon - just RegisterCustomModule. Should I? Some sources mentioned that in a general way, but it did not seem to be warranted here. Not Sure.